# php continue - alternative way?

Tags: php, continue

I just started learning `php` and I have to do something like this which I got it working but I just have a few questions I want to ask for alternate way of doing but eh first of all the br/ is suppose to be with `<>` but somehow if i do that the coding at the bottom will see it as a line break.

Anyways if questions are...

1. With the coding below the outcome will be 0-9 (without 5) but I have to set `$zero=-1` if I put `$zero=0` then the outcome would be 1-9 (without 5) is there a way I don't have to make $zero=-1 and still have the outcome of 0-9 (without 5)?
2. I realized I have to put `$zero++` before the if and continue statement if I put it at the end of the script after `echo "$zero" . "br/";` the script won't run as wanted.  Is this how it is suppose to be or I just don't know the other way of doing it.

Thanks in advance for people replying ^_^

```
$squared = pow(3,2);

echo "\"3 squared is $squared:";
echo "br/";

$zero = -1;
while ($squared > $zero)
{
    $zero++;
    if ($zero == 5)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else if ($squared == $zero)
    {
        echo "$squared\"";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "$zero" . "br/";
    }
}
```

Comment: That `($zero == 5)` is making my OCDs cringe

Comment: Also I don't really understand what is the purpose of your code? What do you want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is (you were almost there :P )

```
$nr = 0;
while ($squared > $nr) {

    if (5 == $nr) {
        $nr++; // add this
        continue;
    } else if ($squared == $nr) {
        echo "$squared\"";
    } else {
        echo "$nr" . "<br/>";
    }
    $nr++; // move to the bottom
}
```

PS: You're welcome @clement

Comment: oops -- changing the code to use `$nr`, you've left one occurrence of `$zero` in there.

Comment: I'm just wondering because I tried reading and they all say continue; is to leave out whatever the requirement is such as in my example is a (5 == $nr) but why do we still need to add $nr++; before continue;

Comment: Also, I realized that $nr++; can be moved to bottom now instead of at the top is it because the $nr++; before the continue; ? Because I know if I take out the $nr++ before the continue; the loop won't skip 5

Comment: @user1850712: exactly. If you remove that, it will go in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop to while ($squared >= $zero) and then set $zero = 0;
Should work!